# Tmux create window failed: index in use: 0

Tags: shell, tmux

I have a script like so that I'd like to create a tmux session with windows with various server connections:

```
tmux new-session -d -s server-connections
tmux new-window -t server-connections:0 -n 't-u14-nickpl' 'ssh T-U14-NickPL'
tmux new-window -t server-connections:1 -n 't-u12-dev1' 'ssh T-U12-Dev1'
tmux attach -t server-connections
```

When I run that file, I get `create window failed: index in use: 0`.  At first I thought maybe the script was executing so quickly it attached to the window at index 0 faster than the command could be run, so I introduced a sleep just to be sure.

```
tmux new-session -d -s server-connections
tmux new-window -t server-connections:0 -n 't-u14-nickpl' 'ssh T-U14-NickPL'
tmux new-window -t server-connections:1 -n 't-u12-dev1' 'ssh T-U12-Dev1'
sleep 4
tmux attach -t server-connections
```

But still I get `create window failed: index in use: 0` and then the sleep would happen.

What do I need to change to bind to that window at index 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new session always has an initial window, so window index 0 is already taken as soon as `new-session` completes. Instead of an explicit `new-window` command, just specify the information with the `new-session` command itself.

```
tmux new-session -d -s server-connections -n 't-u14-nickpl' 'ssh T-U14-NickPL'
tmux new-window -t server-connections:1 -n 't-u12-dev1' 'ssh T-U12-Dev1'
tmux attach -t server-connections
```

Answer (score 18):

chepner's answer is correct, but you can also avoid specifying window numbers by appending windows with the `-a` option:

```
tmux new-window -a -t server-connections -n 't-u14-nickpl' 'ssh T-U14-NickPL'
tmux new-window -a -t server-connections -n 't-u12-dev1' 'ssh T-U12-Dev1'
```